# How to write code for SeriesCoefficient to work for non integral coefficients?

Tags: series-expansion, coefficients

I have a function of $r$ which I expand at $\infty$ using `Series`. It is a complicated and messy function, with a parameter $0 \leq \epsilon < 1$. After expansion, the total series consists of terms like

$$ \left(\frac{r}{M}\right)^{2 + 2\epsilon} \left(\frac{a}{r^2} + r^{2 \epsilon} + ..... \right) $$

I want to collect the coefficients of $r$ from this series expansion which is denoted by `serinf` in the following code block. (I have not copied the entire expansion here, since it is too big. I have uploaded a Mathematica notebook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcy2aeuvtpubw2o/Testing%20Infinity.nb?dl=0), and the series has been saved - it might take a minute or two to evaluate. When I use `SeriesCoefficient` I get back terms with the variable $r$ even though the series was obtained using `Series[f[r], {r,∞, 4}]` which is not what I want.

How do I get the coefficients of different powers of $r$, even those that include real but non-integral symbolic exponents?

Comment: There are ways to handle Puiseux series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) involving terms such as $r^\epsilon$, but not using built-in functionality. 

In your notebook you write "Below is a series which has been expanded at infinity, up to order 4". I'd like to see `f[r]` *before* being expanded into an asymptotic series. 

And there are new(er) `Asymptotic` functions that might be better than `Series` for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let your expression be myExpression. Then to obtain a list of coefficients of the powers of $r$, first extract all the exponents in theExp.  Then supply the list of exponents to `Coefficient`:

```
theExp=Exponent[myExpression,r,List];
theCoeff=Coefficient[myExpression,r,#]&/@ theExp;
```

You can go further and make a table of exponent and coefficient:

```
myTable=MapThread[{#1,#2//N}&,{theExp,theCoeff}];
myTable//MatrixForm
```

with the "//N" meaning to display the coefficient to machine precision.  Or if you want to see the first ten for example:

```
myTable[[1;;10]]//MatrixForm
```

**Update:**

Take for example your portion of the expression above:

```
myExpression = (r/theM)^(2 + 2 \[Epsilon]) (a/r^2 + r^(2 \[Epsilon]))
Exponent[myExpression, r, List]

(* {2 \[Epsilon], 2 + 4 \[Epsilon]} *)
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the coefficients:

```
 theCoeff = Coefficient[Expand@myExpression, r, #] & /@ theExp

(* {(r^2 (r/theM)^(2 \[Epsilon]))/theM^2,0} *)
```

These are not correct.  Should be:

$$
\left\{\frac{a}{m^{2+2\epsilon}},\frac{1}{m^{2+2\epsilon}}\right\}
$$

Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `Exponent[myExpression,r,List]` does not return any exponent that includes $\epsilon$. It looks like it's the same problem again, where Mathematica does not recognise non-integral/symbolic exponents.

Comment: Ok. It seems the exponents of your expression above were identified but when I attempted to retrieve the associated coefficients, Mathematica returned the wrong results.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(r/theM)^(2 + 2 \[Epsilon]) (a/r^2 + r^(2 \[Epsilon]));
Table[PowerExpand@Expand[expr][[j]] /. r -> 1, {j, 1, 
Dimensions[PowerExpand@Expand[expr]][[1]]}]
```

> `{a theM^(-2 - 2 \[Epsilon]), theM^(-2 - 2 \[Epsilon])}`

? We put `r==1` in the `j`-th term of the expanded `expr` to obtain the `j`-th coefficient.